# Array Count returning one despite it containing more than one value

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to populate my tableview with a plist file.

The plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Rows</key>
    <array>
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <string>C</string>
        <string>D</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I populate my array using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.namesArray = [array valueForKey:@"Rows"];
```

and when I log the contents of the plist I get:

```
(
    (
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
)
)
```

however, my number of rows in section seems to be returning 1 from that array.

I've also logged the array count, and It is only returning 1 which I believe is my problem.

Comment: The plist doesn't match the log. Have you edited this code for the question?

Comment: No, the code's unedited. I did manage to solve the problem though using Jacob Relkin's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because there *is* one element in the array - another array.

What you want to do is call `-count` on the first element in the array:

```
NSUInteger count = [[array objectAtIndex:0] count];
```

In the future, when you have arrays with similar structures, you may want to consider flattening them beforehand. I've written a category on `NSArray` that does just that (untested):

```
@interface NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *) flattenedArray;

@end

@implementation NSArray (JRAdditions)

- (NSArray *) flattenedArray {
  if([self count] == 0) return nil;

  NSMutableArray *flattened = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self count]];
  for(id object in [self copy]) {
     @autoreleasepool {
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [flattened addObjectsFromArray:[object flattenedArray]]; //recursive call
        } else {
            [flattened addObject:object];
        }
     }
  }

  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:flattened];
}

@end
```